# Why does this Javascript work in FF3.6? new Date("2010-06-09T19:20:30+01:00");

Tags: javascript, date, cross-browser

Here's the sample code:

```
var d = new Date("2010-06-09T19:20:30+01:00");
document.write(d);
```

On FF3.6 this will give you:

**Wed Jun 09 2010 14:20:30 GMT-0400 (EST)**

Other browers tested; Chrome 5, Safari 4, IE7 give:

**Invalid Date**

I know there is limited to no support for ISO8601 dates, but does anyone know what and/or where the difference is in FF3.6 that allows this to work?

My thought is that FF is just stripping out what it doesn't understand while the others are not.

Has anyone else seen this and/or getting different results from the test script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ECMAScript 5th edition](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) (see §15.9.1.15) adds some support for ISO-8601, and Mozilla has apparently jumped on it (they may even have been the ones pushing it). I didn't think they'd added it to the constructor, and the support is supposed to be a bit simplified, but that doesn't mean Mozilla can't go with the spirit rather than the letter and take anything it can figure out — or *thinks* it can figure out. The actual format supported in the spec is `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`. Your sample date is not quite a match.

Answer (score 1):

ISO 8601 is often used to pass time/date 
info between systems

It allows yyyy-mm-dd alone for midnight GMT of that date,

or the date followed by 'T' and time data,

with optional seconds and milliseconds (after ',').

yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm

yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.xxx

You finish with either  Z for greenwich time, 
nothing, also for Greenwich time, or 
a + or - and the hh:mm offset from GMT.

You can make your own method-
this passes back the local Date,
using the built in method if it is available- 
only firefox, so far.

```
Date.ISO= function(s){
    var D= new Date(s);
    if(D.getDate()) return D;

    var M= [], min= 0,
    Rx=  /([\d:]+)(\.\d+)?(Z|(([+\-])(\d\d):(\d\d))?)?$/;
    D= s.substring(0, 10).split("-");

    if(s.length> 11){
        M= s.substring(11).match(Rx) || [];
        if(M[1]) D= D.concat(M[1].split(":"));
        if(M[2]) D.push(Math.round(M[2]*1000));
    }
    D= D.map(function(itm){return parseInt(itm, 10);});
    D[1]-= 1;
    while(D.length < 7) D.push(0);
    if(M[4]){
        min= parseInt(M[6])*60 + parseInt(M[7], 10);
        if(M[5]== "+") min*= -1;
    }
    D= new Date(Date.UTC.apply(Date, D));
    if(!D.getDate()) throw "Bad Date- " + s;

    if(min) D.setMinutes(D.getMinutes()+ min);
    return D;
}
```

//tests

```
var s= "2010-06-09T19:20:30+01:00";
alert(Date.ISO(s).toUTCString());
```

/*  value: (String)
Safari 5.0: Wed, 09 Jun 2010 18:20:30 GMT

MSIE 8.0: Wed, 9 Jun 2010 18:20:30 UTC

Chrome 5.0.375.70: Wed, 09 Jun 2010 18:20:30 GMT

Opera 10.53: Wed, 09 Jun 2010 18:20:30 GMT

Firefox 3.6.3: Wed, 09 Jun 2010 18:20:30 GMT
*/

Note- To work in IE (and older browsers) you'll need 
to fake the array map method-

```
if(![].map){
    Array.prototype.map= function(fun, scope){
        var L= this.length, A= Array(this.length), i= 0, val;
        if(typeof fun== 'function'){
            while(i< L){
                if(i in this){
                    A[i]= fun.call(scope, this[i], i, this);
                }
                ++i;
            }
            return A;
        }
    }
}
```